# Protractor setup to test remote https

Tags: protractor

Checked through stack overflow and could not find same case.
Namely, I have to on my Win 10 test app https://neesletter.horisen.pro but that app resides remotely and I do not have that app on localhost (just user, pass and URL).

My question is how to setup protractor to test that app?

Answer when I start webdiver is: '

> Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: You need to be running the webdriver locally; it doesn't matter where the app is running, the webdriver runs on the machine you are testing from.

Comment: Thank you @M.Hudson. but why then I have error: 
'Only local connections allowed' 
Already changed IP from localhost to another (and not to 127.0.0.1)
Please, provide me what exactly I have to put in conf.js or elsewhere in order to have test run

Comment: You have to run in locally which means you cannot put anything else than localhost(127.0.0.1). That's the point. Set it up on the same machine you have your website and then make a request that wil launch your tests whenever you want with a simple script.

Comment: Thanks @FCin. Conclusion is simple - in a/m case. it is impossible to run test unless they reside either on remote server or whole app is on localhost. Am I correct?